# Hibernate - Get all entites created in a cascading create

Tags: java, hibernate

If I have an entity with a parent / child relationship (and Cascade=CascadeType.ALL), and call:

```
getSession().save(parent)
```

the primary key of the parent is returned.

Is there a way to access the primary key of the created child?

Regards

Marty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object itself should have it. If not, try calling Session.flush() first.